# Getting null token while sign up in my app

Tags: flutter, dart, rest, mobile

So, I made sign-in and sign-up logic but the point is that every time when I register, the user creates in db but the app still gives me an error to token that I want to save.

Before it was giving me "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String" error

```
class SignUpController extends GetxController {
final isLoading = false.obs;

final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

Future<void> signUpWithUsername() async {
isLoading.value = true;

final String username = usernameController.text.trim();
final String password = passwordController.text.trim();

// Make a POST request to your backend API to register the user
final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse('${AppUrl.url}register'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
  }),
);

if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  // Successful registration

  // Extract the token from the response body
  final token = jsonDecode(response.body)['token'];

  // Decode the token to get the user information
  final Map<String, dynamic> decodedToken = JwtDecoder.decode(token);

  // Save the token and user information for future use
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setString('token', token);
  await prefs.setString('user', jsonEncode(decodedToken));

  // Navigate to the home screen
  Get.offAllNamed(AppRoutes.home);
} else {
  print('Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  Get.snackbar('Error', 'Response body: ${response.body}'.toString(), snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
}
```

Comment: Please share server response also i think something is missing in response.

Comment: I didn't get the point. Can you provide output of response.body in order to clarify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your response.body when response is code 201 too.

```
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

You can check if your token is valid / the content here  : https://jwt.io/.

I think the issue come from the response itself (try to show the response and figure out what's wrong) i think it's not an hard issue (maybe something like ["Token"] instead of ["token"]).

Sending the entire response can help to solve your issue.

Regards, Rémy.